# Order of the documents does not return correct order

Tags: sql-server-2008

This following query does not return me results with 0 documents on ascending order. It directly starts with 1 document in ascending order,though there are 3 rows that have 0 documents.

```
 SELECT UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID)as ParentID, COUNT(Document.ID) as Documentsfrom  HostApplicationLocalData inner join Documenton HostApplicationLocalData.ID=Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID WHEREHostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 6AND Document.Removed=0 ANDHostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000 AND (SharePointURI is not null or ((SharePointURI is nulland Content_ID is not null ) or((HostApplicationLocalData_ID is not null andHostApplicationLocalData_ID != 0 and Content_ID isnull)))) AND HostApplicationLocalData.ParentIDIN('ACETRAVE0001   ','ADVANCED0001   ','ALLENSON0001   ','AMERICAN0001   ','ASSOCIAT0001   ','ATTRACTI00001  ','AUSTRALIA      ','AUTOFINA0001   ','BEAUMONT0001   ','BERGERON0001   ','BLOOMING0001   ','BURNETTT0001   ','BUSINESS MAG   ','BUSINESS0001   ','CAPITALP0001   ','CARLSONS0001   ','CENTRALC0001   ','CHICAGOC0001   ','CHICAGOR0001   ','CIRCUITD0001   ','COMNETEN0001   ','COMPUTER0001   ','COMVEXIN0001   ','CONSUMER MAG   ','CONTINEN0001   ','COWLEYEN0008   ','CRUGEREN0001   ','DISTANTI0001   ','DOLECKIC0001   ','ELECTRO0001    ','ELECTRON0001   ','ELECTRON0003   ','FABRIKAM0001   ','GARDNERS0001   ','GKCLEANI0001   ','GREENLAK0001   ','GREENWOO0001   ','GUNTHARS0004   ','HARVEYEL0001   ','HILLSBRO0001   ','ILSTATE0001    ','IMAGEMAK0001   ','INLANDRE0001   ','INLINESE0001   ','INNERCIT0001   ','INSTATET0001   ','INTEGRAT0001   ','INTERNAL0001   ','INTERNAT0001   ','INTERNAT0002   ','') group byHostApplicationLocalData.ParentID order by Documents asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using inner join, not left join. You would then get only those that have at least 1 document. To get all use LEFT JOIN like this:

```
 SELECT UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) AS ParentID,
        COUNT(Document.ID) AS Documents
 FROM   HostApplicationLocalData
 LEFT JOIN Document ON HostApplicationLocalData.ID = Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID
 WHERE  HostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 6 AND
        Document.Removed = 0 AND
        HostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000 AND
        (
          SharePointURI IS NOT NULL OR
          (
            (
              SharePointURI IS NULL AND
              Content_ID IS NOT NULL
            ) OR
            (
              (HostApplicationLocalData_ID IS NOT NULL AND
              HostApplicationLocalData_ID != 0 AND
              Content_ID IS NULL)
            )
          )
        ) AND
        HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID IN ( 'ACETRAVE0001   ',
                                               'ADVANCED0001   ',
                                               'ALLENSON0001   ',
                                               'AMERICAN0001   ',
                                               'ASSOCIAT0001   ',
                                               'ATTRACTI00001  ',
                                               'AUSTRALIA      ',
                                               'AUTOFINA0001   ',
                                               'BEAUMONT0001   ',
                                               'BERGERON0001   ',
                                               'BLOOMING0001   ',
                                               'BURNETTT0001   ',
                                               'BUSINESS MAG   ',
                                               'BUSINESS0001   ',
                                               'CAPITALP0001   ',
                                               'CARLSONS0001   ',
                                               'CENTRALC0001   ',
                                               'CHICAGOC0001   ',
                                               'CHICAGOR0001   ',
                                               'CIRCUITD0001   ',
                                               'COMNETEN0001   ',
                                               'COMPUTER0001   ',
                                               'COMVEXIN0001   ',
                                               'CONSUMER MAG   ',
                                               'CONTINEN0001   ',
                                               'COWLEYEN0008   ',
                                               'CRUGEREN0001   ',
                                               'DISTANTI0001   ',
                                               'DOLECKIC0001   ',
                                               'ELECTRO0001    ',
                                               'ELECTRON0001   ',
                                               'ELECTRON0003   ',
                                               'FABRIKAM0001   ',
                                               'GARDNERS0001   ',
                                               'GKCLEANI0001   ',
                                               'GREENLAK0001   ',
                                               'GREENWOO0001   ',
                                               'GUNTHARS0004   ',
                                               'HARVEYEL0001   ',
                                               'HILLSBRO0001   ',
                                               'ILSTATE0001    ',
                                               'IMAGEMAK0001   ',
                                               'INLANDRE0001   ',
                                               'INLINESE0001   ',
                                               'INNERCIT0001   ',
                                               'INSTATET0001   ',
                                               'INTEGRAT0001   ',
                                               'INTERNAL0001   ',
                                               'INTERNAT0001   ',
                                               'INTERNAT0002   ', '' )
 GROUP BY HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID
 ORDER BY Documents ASC;
```